# Cpp preprocessor and basename of filename, line number as string

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I'd like to produce a static string of the form `"example.cpp:34"` with the preprocessor, but the `__FILE__` macro will expand to `"lib/example/example.cpp"` and `__LINE__` expands to `34` as an integer.  Can I construct the desired string with the preprocessor? GCC extentions are ok.

**Edit** The most important part here is that I want a static C-style string, so I can't use the `basename` function.  I'm wondering if there's some way in the preprocessor to replicate that functionality, possibly with a boost extension?

Comment: Is C++11 ok? Must the string usable in the preprocessor, or just in compile-time?

Comment: @KennyTM No, I can't use C++11. I want it at compile time.  Boost is also fine.

Comment: Or don't use `__FILE__`, but define your own string literal on top of each file of interest.

Comment: @KennyTM, I think I do want it in the preprocessor. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that adjacent string literals are concatenated:

```
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define FILELINE(line) __FILE__ ":" str(line)
```

Then use it like `FILELINE(__LINE__)`. I don't do this very often so there may be a better way than having to pass the `__LINE__` macro. It works for me anyway, testing with:

```
#include <iostream>

#define str(s) #s
#define FILELINE(line) __FILE__ ":" str(line)

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << FILELINE(__LINE__) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
main.cpp:9
```

Comment: Sure, so I guess the problem is really the basename.  You get main.cpp because you weren't including a file in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use `basename()` as `__FILE__` expands to a const C string

> **__FILE__**
>       This macro expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a C string constant.

```
printf ("%s:%d\n", basename(__FILE__), __LINE__);
```

Comment: I want a static c-string, so it can't be the output of a function.

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor what do you mean the output of a function ? you want to return it from a function ?

Comment: I mean that I want a static string, so I can't use any functions, only the preprocessor to construct it.

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor that's impossible with the C preprocessor, why do you want a static string ? maybe there's another way.

Comment: yeah, I've discovered that is impossible, which is a pity

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get the basename, but oyther than that you can used the stringification preprocessor operator '#', like:

```
#define M__(x,y) x ":" #y
#define M_(x,y) M__(x, y)
#define M M_(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Now `M` will expand to `"lib/example/example.cpp:34"` (given you put it in that file on that line, ofc :))

Answer (score 0):

Well, not only preprocessor has to be used - but it won't be seen to the end user.

When you want `BASENAME()` to be used in some file - use this header file `basename.h`:

```
// basename.h
#include <string.h>

static size_t basename_start_calc(const char* filename)
{
    const char* base = strrchr(filename, '/');
    return base ? (base - filename + 1) : 0;
}
static inline size_t basename_start(const char* filename)
{
    static size_t retval = basename_start_calc(filename);
    return retval;
}
#define STR_(t) #t
#define STR(t) STR_(t)
#define BASENAME()  ((__FILE__ ":" STR(__LINE__)) + basename_start(__FILE__))
```

An [ideone example here](http://ideone.com/lShQhs).

`basename_start(__FILE__)` will be evaluated only once for the given source file. Unfortunately  you can't use this solution in header files - only in source files. You can change it, so it can be used everywhere - but then start of baseline for the given filename will be calculated every time. Just use in `BASENAME()` `basename_start_calc(__FILE__)` instead of `basename_start(__FILE__)`...

I believe this is best you can have automatically.

Of course you can define by hand in every file macro:

```
#define BASENAME()  ("somefile.cpp:" STR(__LINE__))
```

but I am not sure this is what you wanted....